# ExtractValue not working for Deeper XMLs

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath

Scope:
To use ExtractValue() in MYSQL to parse xml data.

Issue faced:
ExtractValue() does not give the desired output.

Example,

For the input xml(column name-xml),

```
<rootData><rootData><rootData><rootData>123</rootData></rootData></rootData></rootData>
```

the ExtractValue(xml,'//rootData') is giving the output as 123, which is correct.

Whereas, For the input xml(column name-xml),

```
<ThisIsALongElemenetUsedForTesting><ThisIsALongElemenetUsedForTesting><ThisIsALongElemenetUsedForTesting><ThisIsALongElemenetUsedForTesting>12</ThisIsALongElemenetUsedForTesting></ThisIsALongElemenetUsedForTesting></ThisIsALongElemenetUsedForTesting></ThisIsALongElemenetUsedForTesting>
```

the ExtractValue(xml,'//ThisIsALongElemenetUsedForTesting') is not giving the correct output. Rather it is given a NULL value.

Note: If a match for the XPATH is not available it would return a empty string and not NULL

Please help me on how the issue can be resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in the MYSQL server itself.

I encountered this issue in the MYSQL Server 5.5, but after I upgraded to version 5.6 this issue seems to have vanished.

This could be a possible issue in the MYSQL Server 5.5, Resolution is to use MYSQL Server version which is 5.6 or above.